# Can anyone help to identify this font?

Tags: font-identification

I know this font looks so familiar, but I'm having trouble finding a font with this Uppercase T... any help would be appreciated!

Thanks[image]

Comment: You can identify what is the font by using the image. Have a look [here](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/).

Answer (score 2):

I like this match:

[TC Kingsley RR Swash Osf Light Italic](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/redrooster/tc-kingsley-rr/tckingsley-rr-swash-osf-light-italic/)

[image]